# How to implement a React Component with sub-components and call them?

Tags: reactjs

How to implement a React component with a similar structure of [react-bootstrap Modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/)?

```
<Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <h1>My Body</h1>
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

I was working a solution like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CardHeader from './CardHeader.jsx'
import CardBody from './CardBody.jsx'
import CardFooter from './CardFooter.jsx'

class Card extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.Header}
        {this.Body}
        {this.Footer}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Card.Header = CardHeader
Card.Body   = CardBody
Card.Footer = CardFooter

export default Card
```

Sub-components(all are equals) and receive a text prop to render:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class CardHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.text}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And calling them:

```
<Card>        
    <Card.Header text='Header'/>
    <Card.Body text='Body'/>
    <Card.Footer text='Footer'/>
</Card>
```

But didn't work!

Comment: What does not work? Are there errors in the console? If you add some text under `{this.props.text}`, is it displayed ?

Comment: You're importing `CardHeader` but your component is named `Header`.

Comment: Without any console.
The Card.jsx renders properly, but the {this.Header} does not renders.

Comment: @Dan, I fixed **Header** to **CardHeader** in **CardHeader.jsx** but still the same. :/

Comment: {this.props.children} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively what you are doing is just rendering the children of the parent component.

So if you just change your `Card` component to...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Card extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Card
```

It will then render anything that you pass into the component.

For exporting and being able to use `Card.Header` etc... you can create a new `const`

```
const card = {
    Header: HeaderComponent,
    Body: BodyComponent,
    Footer: FooterComponent
};

export {
    card as Card
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your components to render their `children`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class CardHeader extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Add static properties to `Card`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CardHeader from './CardHeader.jsx'
import CardBody from './CardBody.jsx'
import CardFooter from './CardFooter.jsx'

class Card extends Component {
  static Header = CardHeader;
  static Body = CardBody;
  static Footer = CardFooter;

  render() {
    return (
      { this.props.children }
    )
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Use it like so:

```
<Card>
  <Card.Header>Header</Card/Header>
  <Card.Body>Body</Card.Body>
  <Card.Footer>Footer</Card.Footer>
</Card>
```